# Reformat Data - Count by Group with either Excel or R

Tags: microsoft-excel, r

Imagine a data file like this, tab separated, imported either into Excel or R:

```
London A
London A
London B
Paris A
Paris B
Paris C
```

I want to transform this into 3 separate count tables (3 because the second column has 3 unique elements A,B and C).
The 3 count tables I want to create would be:

**Count Table for A:**

```
London 2
Paris 1
```

**Count Table for B:**

```
London 1
Paris 1
```

**Count Table for C:**

```
London 0
Paris 1
```

Any simple solution to this either with R or Excel (consider that I have a few hundred cities where I want to count how many A, B and C?

Comment: If appropriate for your requirements, you could create a Pivot Table (easy using Power Query in Excel) with separate columns for `A`, `B` and `C`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps several ways to accomplish this in Excel. The method below would require very little effort. First import your data into excel into columns A and B. If you want three tables, then input a de-duped copy of your cities in 3 different columns. In my case, I input city names in columns D, G and J. [Excel has a de-dupe function in Data Tools.]

Then here are the formulas for cells E2, H2 and K2:

```
E2: =COUNTIFS($A:$A,D2,$B:$B,"A")

H2: =COUNTIFS($A:$A,G2,$B:$B,"B")

K2: =COUNTIFS($A:$A,J2,$B:$B,"C")
```

Copy down your formulas and you're done. Now, I don't know how you are exactly defining a "table" in your question, but I think this gets you started.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common data manipulation problem in R. You can use `table` to get the counts of each element.
Here is a reproducible example:

```
data <- data.frame("city" = c("London","London","London", "Paris", "Paris", "Paris"),"element" = c("A","A","B","A","B","C"))
table(data)
#         element
# city     A B C
#   London 2 1 0
#   Paris  1 1 1

# if you want to save individual columns in separate data frames
data.frame("counts" = table(data)[,"A"])->data_a
data_a
#        counts
# London      2
# Paris       1
data.frame("counts" = table(data)[,"B"])->data_b
data.frame("counts" = table(data)[,"C"])->data_c
```

If you want the reverse i.e. counts of city, then use

```
table(data$element, data$city)
#    London Paris
#  A      2     1
#  B      1     1
#  C      0     1
```